# Rails: favorite a product and use ajax for the favorite/unfavorite button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm looping through an array of products and I'm rending the favorite/unfavorite button next to each product :

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<%= product.title %>
<%= product.price %>
<%= product.description %>

<div id="favorites_grid">
  <%= render partial: 'favorite_products/favorite', locals: { product: product } %>
</div>
```

The partial with the favorite buttons _favorite.html.erb:

```
<% unless current_user.favorite_products.exists?(product.id) %>
  <%= link_to "Favorite", create_favorited_product_path(product_id: product.id), method: :post, :remote => true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Unfavorite", favorited_product_path(product_id: product.id), method: :delete, :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

The table schema:

```
class CreateFavorites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :favorites do |t|
      t.references :favorited, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The model associations:

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
end

class Consumer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_products, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Product'
end
```

The controller:

```
def create
  @favorite = Favorite(favorited: @product, user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ favorite.save
        flash.now[:success] = "You have successfully added this product to your favorites list."
        format.js { render 'favorite.js.erb' }
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Something when wrong!"
        format.js { render 'favorite.js.erb' }
      end
    end
end

def destroy
  @favorite = Favorite.where(favorited_id: @product.id, user_id: current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    @favorite.first.destroy
    flash.now[:success] = "You have successfully removed this product from your favorites list."
    format.js { render 'favorite.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

I have the turbolinks disabled.

The favorite.js.erb:

```
$('#favorites_grid').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'favorite_products/favorite', locals: { product: @product } ) %>");
$("#flash").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'layouts/messages') %>");
```

And the routes:

```
post 'favorite_products', to: 'favorite_products#create', defaults: { format: 'js' }, :as => 'create_favorited_product'
delete 'favorite_products/id', to: 'favorite_products#destroy', defaults: { format: 'js' }, :as => 'favorited_product'
```

The favorite/unfavorite button is rendering correctly next to each product on the first page load. Also the button works just fine, it favorites/unfavorites the product that its associated with.

The only issue I'm having is that.... if I click on any product to favorite or unfavorite, the ajax will render the first button as favorite/unfavorite. In other words the ajax is not rending the correct button according to the current status(favorite or unfavorite). If i refresh the page everything shows correctly.

Any ideas on how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is putting `<div id="favorites_grid">` inside the product loop, that leads to having multiple divs which has the same `id`. Then when you look up the div to replace, you always get the first one to replace.

My suggestion is

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.title %>
  <%= product.price %>
  <%= product.description %>

  <div id="favorites_grid_<%= product.id %>">
    <%= render partial: 'favorite_products/favorite', locals: { product: product } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then you can look up the exact grid rely on `favorites_grid_#{product.id}` inside your `favorite.js.erb`

Try to update:

```
$("#favorites_grid_<%= @product.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'favorite_products/favorite', locals: { product: @product } ) %>");
$("#flash").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'layouts/messages') %>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Hoa.Nguyen .. unfortunately its not working, now no button   changes. Also I don't get an error in the rails console. Are you sure this is right `<div id="favorites_grid_#{product.id}">` ??

Comment: Keep the inspect window open (You're using chrome I guess), and click that link, you will see a JS response, could you give the detail of it?

Comment: I'm using safari... no errors nothing is showing in the browser console!

Comment: If you're using safari, then you can switch to Network tab, and click the link. 1 js file will be fetched to your browser in the `Name` column, you can click into it and see the content.

Comment: the first one is this: `curl 'https://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1' \
-XGET` is this the correct one?

Comment: its name should be something with `favorite.js`, could you double check again? please make sure that you've clicked the favorite link.

Comment: nope it not there ... only one i could find that it relavant `curl 'https://localhost:3000/assets/favorite_products.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1' \
-XGET`

Comment: And what is the response of it?

Comment: `(function() {


}).call(this);`

Comment: hmm, weird. Could you inspect your html body and send me the generated `favorites_grid_<id>` div? We need to make sure our html has been generated with the expected outcome.

Comment: We need the `div` which is the parent div of this tag a, could you get it?

Comment: `<div id="favorites_grid_#{product.id}">
        <a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/favorite_products/id?product_id=68">Unfavorite</a>

    </div>`

Comment: ok, I think we see the root cause then. Back to our code, the file which includes `<% @products.each do |product| %>`, let's update `<div id="favorites_grid_#{product.id}">` to `<div id="favorites_grid_<%= product.id %>">`, and could you try running it again? Sorry, I used `Haml` syntax instead of `Erb` there

Comment: It works just fine @Hoa.Nguyen,. Change your answer so I can upvote and accept it! Thanks for the help and your time :)))

Comment: And don't forget to mark my answer is the right one, thanks @Theopap